# wrong google play services version

Tags: android, google-play-services

I just made an app for android, so I try to upload it for ditribution through the play store, but when I upload the apk file, an error shows up saying that I use version 5208000 of the google play services, it say that I need to use version 5100000 or lower, it makes no sense it was just the version that the sdk manager downloaded. It does not have an option to download the previous one, I try to use compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77' but it says that it is not found. How can I download it? I downloaded the google play services for froyo, I tried using the support library and nothing works. How come I cant use the latest version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Play Services 5.2.08 is the [Google Fit Developer Preview](https://developers.google.com/fit/preview) and not yet available on all devices. You should use `5.0.89` (which replaced `5.0.77` due to issues in `5.0.77`) for production apps at this time.

Comment: 5.2.08 is the one that the sdk mannager automatucally downloaded, and there is no option to download any previous versions. I tried specifying version 5.1 but it says it is not installed

Comment: And when you use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'`?

Comment: Gradle only downloads on demand (i.e., the first time you include a certain dependency), although you can get a list of Google Play Service versions by looking at `{sdk_directory}\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services\maven-metadata.xml`

Comment: Can someone explain where one might find information on which version to use, for future revisions?

Comment: @tmalseed - http://gradleplease.appspot.com/ is a great resource for determining the correct Gradle versions. In this particular case, Android Studio now recommends the correct (latest production) version for the support library and Google Play Services.